# How to bundle all app with all required dependencies into one file?

Tags: webpack, bundling-and-minification

I need to bundle all my nestjs app into one file and it should contain all required dependencies. For example I have created simple nest app with

```
nest new testProject
```

And added webpack.package.js file:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: ['./dist/main.js'],
    target: 'node',
    output: {
        path: `${process.cwd()}/bin`,
        filename: 'getState.js',
        libraryTarget: 'umd'
    }
};
```

After taht I transpile ts ty es5 with `npm build`. And run `npx webpack` to bundle my js. But there are errors with node modules, I don't understand why webpack can't find them

```
Hash: 281791709eed73aedd9f
Version: webpack 4.41.5
Time: 1464ms
Built at: 2020-01-29 17:45:17
1 asset
Entrypoint main = getState.js
    [2] ./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js + 1 modules 4.75 KiB {0} [built]
|    2 modules
    [63] external "http" 42 bytes {0} [built]
    [93] ./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/scheduler/asap.js + 3 modules 3.7 KiB {0} [built]
|    4 modules
    [97] external "crypto" 42 bytes {0} [built]
    [142] ./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/index.js + 19 modules 35.8 KiB {0} [built]
|    20 modules
    [151] ./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/scheduled/scheduled.js + 5 modules 5.14 KiB {0} [built]
|    6 modules
    [171] external "os" 42 bytes {0} [built]
    [182] ./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/operators/index.js + 97 modules 176 KiB {0} [built]
|    98 modules
    [251] ./node_modules/@nestjs/core/helpers sync 160 bytes {0} [optional] [built]
    [293] ./dist/app.service.js 926 bytes {0} [built]
    [294] multi ./dist/main.js 28 bytes {0} [built]
    [295] ./dist/main.js 340 bytes {0} [built]
    [423] ./node_modules/@nestjs/common/utils sync 160 bytes {0} [optional] [built]
    [658] ./dist/app.module.js 1.07 KiB {0} [built]
    [659] ./dist/app.controller.js 1.49 KiB {0} [built]
+ 645 hidden modules

    ERROR in ./node_modules/@nestjs/core/nest-application.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@nestjs/microservices' in '/home/aleksandr/IdeaProjects/test-project/node_modules/@nestjs/core'
@ ./node_modules/@nestjs/core/nest-application.js 109:115-147
@ ./node_modules/@nestjs/core/index.js
@ ./dist/main.js
@ multi ./dist/main.js
```

Comment: Did you try npm install before building?

Comment: yea, of cource. I run this app and it response 'Hello world' on localhost:3000.

Comment: ok, may be you have specified wrong entry point? `dist` seems to be a target path, but entryPoint expects to be the input path?

Comment: I don't understand you. dist/main.js is root file for my project. I can even exec `node ./dist/main.js` and it will run my app. Which input path do you mean?

Comment: I am just giving a hint here because I am still not sure why nestjs build doesn't include all the dependencies [may be dependencies internal mechanism is different in different OS/Architecture] so usually I transfer my "package.lock.json" to server and run "npm i" there which solves all my dependencies issue.